# Difference between oncreatecontextmenu and onLongClickListener

Tags: android, contextmenu, onlongclicklistener

I am developing a music application.I want song list that on a long click can give some options.So what can I use for it(contextmenu or OnLongClickListener).Can you tell be the differnce between them.And if possible little more about OnLongClickListener()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnLongClickListener is used to do some task when longclick is received from user. Here programmer can do any task.

OnCreateContextMenu is used to create context menu which is like our mouse right click, which show some menu in our PC. Here the context menu will be displayed only when longclick is received from user.

Context menu is the task for long click action like any normal task which you do with OnLongClickListener. But context menu is predefined and fixed.

I hope it may help you.